# MongoDB Aggregation: Return the object in an array which contains a matching value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB aggregation pipeline, I want to retrieve the matching objects for a number from the data (see below)

**For this number "9999933333", I would like the result like this:**

```
  'matchingObjects':[ 
    {
      id:'efg',
      phoneNumbers: ['9999933333','9999944444']
   },
   {
      id:'hij',
      phoneNumbers: ['9999933333','9999955555']
   }
  ]
```

**Here is the Data (after previous stages):**

```
{
 id: 123
 contactsOfAppUsers:[
   {
    id:'abc',
    contactsArray: ['9999911111','9999922222']
   },
   {
    id:'efg',
    contactsArray: ['9999933333','9999944444']
   },
   {
    id:'hij',
    contactsArray: ['9999955555','9999933333']
   }
 ]
}
```

I tried this, which gives boolean values which is not what I want.

```
db.phNumbers.aggregate([
  {// Previous stage},
  {
    $addFields: {
      'matchingObjects': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$contactsOfAppUsers',
          'as': 'cc',
          'in': {
            '$in': [
              '9999933333','$$cc.contactsArray'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
])
```

Comment: I see here $filter as more suitable: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5fyiMg_5fdF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    matchingObjects: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$contactsOfAppUsers",
        as: "numbers",
        cond: {
          $in: [
            "9999933333",
            "$$numbers.contactsArray"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q5xlO1ZOMcb

**EDIT**

If you really want to rename the field to `phoneNumbers`, try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      matchingObjects: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$contactsOfAppUsers",
          as: "numbers",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "9999933333",
              "$$numbers.contactsArray"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchingObjects: {
        $map: {
          input: "$matchingObjects",
          as: "matchingObjects",
          in: {
            phoneNumbers: "$$matchingObjects.contactsArray",
            id: "$$matchingObjects.id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cXkFo59YdMy